# Winform: Placing a panel over multiple panels

Tags: c#, winforms

Need this:

[image]

But Getting this:

[image]

Do I need to custom draw rectangle to do the above? Plus I need to show a number inside the panel. Any ideas how to go about this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't put the third panel (the horizontal one) inside one of the other panels. Once all three panels share the same parent, right click on the horizontal one and select "Bring to front".

You could also go to View -> Other Windows -> Document Outline (Ctrl + W,U) and change the oder of the items there to specify which controls have a higher "stacking order".

To show a number inside the panel simply use a Label and set its text property to number character you would like to display.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Rather than dragging it with mouse, using the keyboard to place it did the trick. Thanks.